# Why is the option text sent when form submitted instead of "value" if value is not set?

Tags: html, forms

I am only seeing this occur in some older version of IE. I don't see this behavior in Chrome or Firefox. We have a form with this code:

```html
<div class="small-12 medium-3 column hide" id="special-set-div">
  <label>Special Set?
        <select id="special-set" name="special_set">
          <option value>Select</option>
          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
          <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
      </label>
</div>
```

When the form is submitted, the server is reading "Select" from this parameter. Do I need to manually assign the value to an empty string? Is there any documentation of this behavior? I can't seem to find any mention of this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Select` as option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option) states about value attribute:

> value = string
>   Provides a value for element.
>   If there isn't, the value of an option element is the textContent of the element.

So yes, this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question perfectly.